# Windows 10 Guest freezes on initial boot under virtualbox in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

So I have this small project I need to do in Visual Studio, and all I have to do it on is this old machine running Ubuntu 16.04. I understand I can get a free install of Windows 10 through the Edge browser testing link [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

So I have got virtualbox installed, and I have this .ova file downloaded.

At first it would fail immediately on import. I had to disable quick boot. I struggled to figure out how and honestly I can't communicate which steps eventually worked.

The current status is that when I start the VM I get this really pretty Windows 10 logo. It is nice but this is all that it does. [Here is a gist with the logs](https://gist.github.com/gooddadmike/7520d73fedd2cf77061c7f1e01ad2954)

Here are my machine details. [image: abot my ubuntu install]

This is a 2014-ish Toshiba Satellite c55-a5282

Any help appreciated. I'm totally stuck here.

Comment: Did you read the [installation instructions](https://az792536.vo.msecnd.net/vms/release_notes_license_terms_8_1_15.pdf)? How much RAM did you assign to the virtual machine?

Comment: Yep. I added 2048

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may have an old version of VirtualBox.

I had this problem with a Windows 10 guest on a Ubuntu 16.04 host and solved it by removing VirtualBox 5.0.40 (`sudo apt-get autoremove 'virtualbox*'`) and then installing VirtualBox 5.1.24.  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Use `VirtualBox --help` to see your version of VirtualBox.

Comment: I actually just abandoned this effort, but seeing as how this answer solved it for others and has proven useful I accepted.

Answer (score 2):

on that version 5.0.40 you can try to unset paravirtualization.
on your VM configuration Under System – Acceleration you must set Paravirtualization to None.